# add attributes via string to dynamic object

Tags: c#, wcf, c#-4.0, dynamic, reflection

I have the following definition:

```
public class cell : DynamicObject {

}

[DataContract]
public class rows {
  [DataMember]
   public List<cell> rows;
}
```

Later in the code I do:

```
dynamic dtCell = new cell();
```

I need to be able to create attributes with different names every time. So I'm able to get json like:

```
{ color: 'red', category: 'car'} or { country: 'US', city: 'Tampa', county: '...', ... }
```

How can I create attributes to a dynamic object just like adding attributes to a dictionary in javascript or something like that.

I tried: `dtCell.GetType().GetProperty('city')` as I found in a couple of posts and the object return is `null`.

When I do:

`dtCell.GetType().GetProperty('city').SetValue(dtCell, 'Tampa', null)`

I get the exception: `dtCell.GetType().GetProperty("CustomerId").SetValue(dtCell, 3, null)' threw an exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException'    dynamic {System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException}`

Help is appreciated!!!

Comment: After you get the `PropertyInfo` you have to then grab the `GetSetMethod` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2ef4d5h3.aspx and run the invoke against that. Basically you're invoking the wrong method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of DynamicObject, you can use Dictionary. For ex,

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    {"country","US"},  {"city","Tampa"},  {"county","..."}
};

var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(dict);
```

would give `{"country":"US","city":"Tampa","county":"..."}`

Anonymous classes can be used too

```
var obj = new { color = "red", category = "car" };
var json2 = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(obj);
```

Comment: Wouldn't this solution be serialized by WCF as {key:country, value:US}...? I tried this approach seems like I have to write my own serializer...

Comment: @user1791567 You can change the WCF's default Json serializer with `JavaScriptSerializer` or `Json.Net`.

Comment: @user1791567 You can also return `Stream` Which means you can use any serializer, write the result to MemoryStream and return that stream.

Comment: How can I change the serializer? Any example ?

Comment: @user1791567 search for `IDispatchMessageFormatter`.